# A word similar to hiccup?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I just had a nasty hiccup attack, and I want to know if there's a synonym for this nasty phenomena.

Comment: Hiccough. Diaphragm spasm fit.

Comment: Being drunk in a cartoon.

Comment: Diaphragm spasm fit sounds brilliant, @Andy but is there a single word to describe this fit... (and, yeah, I can totally imagine that drunk scene with this diaphragm spasm fit, especially in Tom and Jerry)

Comment: .@Calypto that's why I said it as a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: @Andy I think 'A spasmodic contraction of the diaphragm' is the full medical description. The worst-ev er attack lasted for 68 years. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Osborne_(hiccups)

Comment: @WS2 Amazing article. Never knew about Osborne and his 68 years long hiccup... a hiccup every ten seconds... that's awful. And, here I was boasting about my "20 minutes" long hiccup. Tsk tsk. Anyways, great news. Thanks WS2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind medical jargon, a *[singultus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/singultus) episode* (pron. \siŋ-ˈgəl-təs\ ) is synonymous with the colloquial phrase *hiccup attack*.

Comment: I guess I will have to do with this singultus since that's the concluding answer. But, frankly, the best synonym turned out to be a phrase by Andy - Diaphragm Spasm Fit.

Answer (score 3):

[**Singultus**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/singultus) is the medical term for a bout of the hiccups.

Answer (score 1):

**[Yex](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yex)**:

> To hiccough. [Written also yox, yux.] [Obs. or Prov. Eng.]
>
> He yexeth and he speaketh through the nose. --Chaucer...."The **excessive yex**." --Holland.

Comment: You don't read Chaucer? ;-)

Comment: Great. @ThirdNews

Answer (score 1):

"Belching" would be a close to.

Comment: Yeah, "periodical belching" could definitely be considered.